# Source of the idea of "enough to square" - "כדי לרבע"

Tags: sources-mekorot, shiurim-measurements, sukkah, mezuzah

IIRC the idea of "to square" addresses two main issues - measuring a minimal Succah and a minimal house for Mezzuzah (I'll focus on the first but the discussion on the later is similar).

IIRC the basic measurement that the Gemmorah does is 7x7 Tfochim (49sq.T). [Rambam Succah 4.7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Shofar%2C_Sukkah_and_Lulav.4.7?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) uses the term "כדי לרבע" *unexplained* and the Achronim (see Taz, Bac"h and others on Shu"A) have a great discussion whether it means:

- "**of equal footage**", like a Succah 1x49 Tfachim (Ta"Z) or
- any form that "**a square 7x7 Succah can fit in it**", like a round hut (Ba"ch).

What is the Talmudic source for both opinions?

---

EDIT: in Likutim on Rambam I have found the following source:

> **הלכה א**: רחבה אין פחות מז"ט על ז"ט. ולעניין אם ארוך יותר מז' ומשלים לרוחב שהוא פחות מז' עמ"ש בזה בש"י ריש סוכה והוא מחלוקת בין בבלי וירושלימי. (קובץ)

Who is ש"י, where are those Bavli and Yerushalmi and who's Kovetz?

Comment: Where do you see that Taz holds a 1x49 sukkah is ok?

Comment: I don’t understand how anyone could say “of equal footage,” when Sukkah 7b-8b is pretty explicit that you need it to encompass a square, and we pasken like that Gemara (adjusted for 7x7 tefachim instead of 4x4 Amos).

Comment: This is just an idea, but the ש״י could be רש״י

Comment: See Oz VeHadar Sukkah 3a, Tosafos ד"ה לא נצרכה and Hagahos VeTizyunim אות נ. Seems to be a question of how to read Tosafos

Comment: Kovetz is a work on Rambam by R Nachum Trebitsch. He also wrote a commentary on the Yerushalmi called Sh’lom Yerushalayim, which is what he is referring to in his comment here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be based on the discussion in [Sukkah 7b - 8a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.7b.19?lang=bi) which analyzes R. Yochanan’s opinion that a circular *sukkah* is *kosher* if it has a circumference such that 24 people can fit around it.

Comment: Please see my edit, I can't find an opinion in Gemmorah of Koshering a 1x49 Succha

Comment: @AlBerko you didn't ask for a Gemara with that exact case.